# Why are Redux's state functions called reducers?

Tags: javascript, redux

This is [a part the official Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions):

> It’s called a reducer because it’s the type of function you would pass
>   to `Array.prototype.reduce(reducer, ?initialValue)`

It doesn't make much sense to me. Could somebody explain to me why they are actually called reducers? The fact that they return a default value (or they have a default argument value) doesn't make them reducers IMHO.

Comment: They are reducers exactly because they behave like the function you pass to `reduce`, which has access to the default value and another value, and gives you back your potentially transformed default value. `state -> action -> state`

Comment: a rose by any other name... probably marketing; map/reduce is a buzzword now...

Comment: that;s why you must start to think yourself and don't rely on a framework. A framwork is mostly work of one or a few developers with their own vision how to solve a problem adapted by internet users. Some frameworks got it right however mostly don't. a blizz of a kiss, the same or less is not a solution. This is just an example of many out there.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

> The fact that they return a default value (or they have a default
>   argument value) doesn't make them reducers IMHO.

Reducers do not *just* return default values.  They always return the accumulation of the state (based on all previous and current actions).

Therefore, they act as a *reducer* of state.  Each time a redux reducer is called, the state is passed in with the action `(state, action)`.  This state is then *reduced* (or accumulated) based on the action, and then the next state is returned.  This is one cycle of the classic `fold` or `reduce` function.

As @azium summed up with `state -> action -> state`.

Comment: Humm by this logic shouldn't they be called increasers rather than reducers? No data is ever being reduced its being added :/ lol

Comment: @JamieHutber I think you slightly miss the meaning of reducer in this context.  reducer is taking a stream (or collection) of items and combining them into a single item.  In this case, all actions (through time) are the collection of items, and the state is the single item.  Make sense?

Comment: lol I see now. So its basically just concating them. Why not call it merger then :P THanks for making it clear to me :)

Comment: Thank goodness I am not the only one thinks the name reducer is a bit off at least 2,000 views on this post at the time I write this. The fact that someone is even willing to spin up the effort to dig up why it is called reducer doesn't it imply it is indeed a bit off ? If It's called a reducer because it's the type of function you would pass to Array.prototype.reduce, it is like let's call orange a juicer because we pass orange to object.prototype.juicer, or shouldn’t we call it a fruit ?

Comment: I agree, it's not at all an intuitive name. Logically, to be called reducer it should reduce something. If it took a whole array of state changes along with a state and combined them into a single state all at once, then it would be an intuitive name.

Comment: @JamieHutber by idea they are reducing the size of the array they are applied to. You can think of them as sort of filters + shared context (aka aggregator or state) where one can post his totals or whatever one might need. In the general case they reduce an array of data to a single value(s) like a total.

Comment: At this point, the term `(state) reducer` just is what it is - even though it confuses me every time. I process it in my mind as a `state transition function`.

Comment: `f(old_state, action) => new_state` 

An example would be  `f(apple_state_green, change_color) => apple_state_red`  

Here I would chose to name `f` as `stateChanger` instead of `reducer`. 

We are not reducing 5 apples to 3 apples. 

We are changing apple's state from green to red as defined in the state change action definition.

Comment: @MehmetKaplan in the JavaScript `reduce` function the callback is the signature: `(acc, next) => acc`.  The result of the reduce could be any number of transformations.  In general terms, a transition from green to red is a reduction.  You are taking an old state `green` and a new state `red` and *reducing* them to the next state `red`.

Comment: @DavinTryon, I guess you are referring to the `reduce` function of the arrays (not the objects as general). That reduces N elements of an array to a single value. Its purpose, as far as I interpret, is not to convert an array to another array. In redux, we are trying convert a state to another state, which is in simplest form, change of state. (On the other hand, I agree naming is hard and there is no method to satisfy all.)

Answer (score 21):

If you consider the series of actions in your app to be like a list, or maybe more like a stream, it might make more sense.

Take this contrived example:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'].reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.length, 0)
```

The first argument is a function of the form `(Int, String) => Int`. Along with an initial value, you pass `reduce` what might be called a "reducer function", and you get the result of processing the series of items. So you might say, the reducer function describes what is done with each successive individual item to change the result. In other words, the reducer function takes the previously output and the next value, and it calculates the next output.

This is analogous to what a Redux reducer does: it takes the previous state and the current action, and it calculate the next state.

In true functional programming style, you can conceptually erase the meaning applied to the arguments and the result, and just focus on the "shape" of the inputs and output.

In practice, Redux reducers are typically orthogonal, in the sense that for a given action, they don't all make changes to the same properties, which makes it easy to split their responsibilities and aggregate the output with `combineReducers`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it makes more sense when I'm thinking about actions more like about a stream. Cool, apretiate that!

Comment: This was how I initially understood it, but this doesn't seem to be how any of the store implementations I've seen thus far have implemented it...

Answer (score 16):

As already mentioned the name is related to the concept of a reducer in functional programming. You may also find the Merriam-Webster dictionary definition of reducer helpful:

> 1a. to draw together or cause to converge : consolidate (reduce all the questions to one)

The reducer consolidates actions into a single object representing application state.

Answer (score 8):

> The reason why a [redux reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) is called a `reducer` is because you could "reduce" a `collection of actions` and an `initial state` (of the store) on which to perform these actions to get the resulting `final state`.

How? To answer that, let me define a reducer again:

> The [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method applies a `function (reducer)` against an `accumulator` and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

And what does a redux reducer do?

> The reducer is a pure `function` that takes the current state and an
>   action, and returns the next state. Note that the state is `accumulated` as each action on the collection is applied to change this state.

So given a `collection of actions`, the reducer is applied on each value of the collection (from left-to-right). The first time, it returns the `initial value`. Now the reducer is applied again on this initial state and the first action to return the next state. And the next collection item (action) is applied each time on the `current state` to get the `next state` until it reaches the end of the array. And then, you get `the final state`. How cool is that!

Answer (score 6):

The author think state as the accumulator of the reduce function. Ex:

```
Final State = [Action1, Action2, ..., ActionN].reduce(reducer, Initial State);
```

The reduce function is coming from Functional Programming, the name "reducer" is also coming from FP.

I don't like using that name here. Because I don't see the world as a single value result after actions. The state here is an object. For example:

```
['eat', 'sleep'] === [addTodo('eat'), addTodo('sleep')].reduce(reducer, []);
```

This **Reducer** reduces nothing at all. And I don't care it reduce anything or not. Naming it as **Transducer** will make more sense.

Answer (score 5):

We know where Reducers are coming from (functional programming), and why they might be considered to be doing reducing work (reduce n input items to a single return value - which is just what normal functions are supposted do). 
However: The name is just a name, like rose is the name for a rose. Do not think too much. Redux progammers are IT people, they are locked in their context and there it makes sense. The rest of us have to accept the inventor's right to call a blue dog a yellow cat ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is, arguably, a poor choice of naming. (Subjective comment, no offence, I agree naming is hard and you can not make everybody happy at the same time.)

I know people, just because of this naming, had hard time to adapt the redux. When I told them, it is a simple "state changer" then everything magically became fine. So rather than using the word `reducer`, we started using `stateChanger` as the reducers' function names.

**Trivia:**

From computer science perspective, a reduction is employing an algorithm of a problem to solve another problem (solving one can solve the other as well). For example SAT class problems reduce to the 3SAT class. It means all SAT problems can be solved by a solver of the 3SAT class problems. (For whom the bell tolls - or simply interested - you can refer to the greatest living mind [Scott Aaranson's lecture on the subject](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-080-great-ideas-in-theoretical-computer-science-spring-2008/lecture-notes/lec10.pdf)) As you see the reducing here has nothing to do with redux's reducers.

**Our approach:**

On the other hand, redux's play area is more like the "state machines". So a reducer is actually a state changer function. That is why we, in our company, are using the `stateChanger` naming in order to avoid thinking about what the function was doing each time. (Yes that few milliseconds are what we are trying to avoid, because it sometimes annoys us because we lose our concentration on the main problem. And since redux is the heart of the data on the presentation layer, we came the same position frequently and avoiding even milliseconds is valuable for us.)

Answer (score 2):

Calling Redux reducers *reducers* is semantically incorrect and doesn't make much sense.
That's why the author is confused.

A reducer is *a function that **reduces a set of values** to a single value*.
We can also say that it *folds the values* - thus the classic `fold()` fn in functional programming.

Since Redux reducer *does not* fold a set of values, but applies an action to a state and always returns the same shape (`State -> Action -> State`) - it should be called *applicator* or *applier*.
But, since we have to always return the same *shape* of the state, and not just smth completely unrelated - we'd make much more sense calling Redux state applicators *changers*, *transformers* or *mutators*.
And, it indeed has become commonplace to use terms like *'mutate the state'* and *'state mutator'*.

But Redux sounds just so much cooler, than *Applux* or *Mutux* :)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers explain well why it's named as it is but let's try naming more things...

```
const origState = 0;
const actionOperators = {
    increment: (origState) => origState++,
    decrement: (origState) => origState--,
};
const anOperator = (aState, anAction) => actionOperators[anAction](aState);
const actions = ['increment', 'decrement', 'increment'];
const finalState = actions.reduce(anOperator, origState);
```

First, `reduce` could be called `use anOperator with every action name and accumulated state, starting with origState`. In smalltalk it's called `actions inject: origState into: anOperator`.
But what do actually you inject into the operator? The origState AND the action names. So even in Smalltalk method names are not very clear.

`actionOperators[increment]` is a Reducer, but I would rather call it and actionOperator because it's implemented for each action. The state is just an argument (and another one as return value).

Reducer is however a better word to be on top of google search results. It's also similar to Redux.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite see how a Redux reducer directly mapped to the function you use with `reduce`, so here's a couple of examples to see how they match up.

First a standard reducer (called 'accumulator' in MDN) function from the [MDN Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Examples) documentation and then a simplified example of Dan Abramov's [`Counter.js`](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/64e2c4adce2b4918c96c3db2b44d8f68#file-counter-js) at the end of his ['You might not need Redux' blog post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367).

- `sum` adds a value to the accumulator
- `reducer` adds/subtracts a value to/from the accumulator.

In both cases here the 'state' is just an integer.

You are 'accumulating' the actions into the state. This is also the immutable way to modify any JavaScript object.

```js
const sum = function(acc, val) {
    return acc + val;
};

const reducer = function(state, action) {
    switch (action) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

console.log('sum', [1, -1, 1].reduce(sum, 0));

console.log('reduce', ['INCREMENT', 'DECREMENT', 'INCREMENT'].reduce(reducer, 0));

console.log('sum', [1, 1, 1].reduce(sum, 0));

console.log('reduce', ['INCREMENT', 'INCREMENT', 'INCREMENT'].reduce(reducer, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code below you just need to think of the accumulator as the actions and currentValue as a state in redux context. with this example you will find out why they name it as a reducer too.

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

// Main operation is 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
// but think of it as a stack like this: 

// | 2 | | 3 | | 4 | 
// |_1_| |_3_| |_6_| | 10 | => the 10 is in result

console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10
```

The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on 
 each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.